# Very basic cumulative Distribution function problem.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let X ~ U[0,5]. Find cumulative distribution function of Y=min(2,x)

P(Y $\le$ t) = P (min(2,x) $\le$ t) = 1 - P (min(2,x)>t) = 1-P(2>x   and x>t)

for t<0 we have P(Y $\le$ t)=0

for t $\in$ [0,2) we have P(Y ≤ t)= 1-P(2>x   and x>t) = 1-P(x>t)=P(x$\le$t)=$\frac{1}{5}$$\int_0^t \! 1 \, \mathrm{d}x.$=$\frac{t}{5}$

for t$\in$[2,+${\displaystyle \infty}$) we have P(Y ≤ t)=1

But when we will calculate a probability density function we get : 
 for $t \in [0,2)$  we have $\frac{1}{5}$ and for $t \notin [0,2)$ we have 0. So it seems that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \! ϱ_y \, \mathrm{d}x.=\frac{2}{5}$$.
Where is mistake in my justification ?.

Comment: The probability density has a delta function of value $\frac{3}{5}$ at $t=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> P(Y $\le$ t) = P (min(2,x) $\le$ t) = 1 - P (min(2,x)>t) = 1-P(2>x   and x>t)

No.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y\leq t) &= \mathsf P(X\leq t\cap 2\leq t) \qquad \star\text{ note: }2\leq t\text{, not }x\\[1ex] &= \mathsf P(X\leq t)\cdot\mathbf 1_{2\leq t}\\[1ex]&=\begin{cases}0 &:& t<2\\2/5 &:& t=2 &\star\text{ note: this is a point with a probability mass.}\\t/5 &:& 2< t < 5\\ 1 & :& 5\leq t\end{cases}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

The probability density has a delta function of value $\frac{3}{5}$ at $t=2$.